# is google still favouring soap web services over rest ones?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

A couple of years ago, while many where getting on the rest wagon, google seemed to be consistent on their use of soap for their web services.

I'd like to know if nowdays is still so, or if google is giving more importance to rest web services

It would also be useful to know which style is prefered by developers, that is which interface is more used...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't really matter what they are using because in most cases they provide a client library to access their API. At that point, as a developer it makes no difference whether they are using SOAP Web Services or RESTful ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, or fortunately? I know that as a developer, I'd much rather use Google's client library than having to code my own REST or SOAP client for their API. That said, I can see how this would be an unfortunate thing. For example, I could be working in a language not supported by Google. Having everything hidden behind a client library would mean that I'd have to reverse engineer the RPC calls rather than using documented ones.

Comment: @quanticle In most cases that I have seen, client libraries simply return the developer back to doing RPC.  Which defeats the point of building the RESTful API.

Comment: @quanticle  Case in point, show me a client library that takes advantage of dynamic hypermedia.